# why SHL AL does not always multiply register AL by 2

Tags: assembly, x86

why SHL AL does not always multiply register AL by 2>

in my assembler I have

```
MOV AL, 5

SHL AL

END
```

when i run this in the assembler it works for everything? But i can't find when it doesn't work or am I completely wrong.

Comment: It's always identical to `add al,al` or to multiplying by 2.  (And then truncating the result to 8 bits to fit in AL, of course).

Comment: Please don't make more work for others by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under a [CC BY-SA license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0), for SE to distribute the content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By SE policy, the non-vandalized version is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. Please see: [How does deleting work? …](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221). If permitted to delete, there's a "delete" button below the post, on the left, but it's only in browsers, not the mobile app.

Comment: @Makyen: You can't delete your own question when there are answers with upvotes.

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks. The requirements are a bit more complex than what can be easily communicated in a comment, which is why I linked to a FAQ Q&A which gives a full and complete explanation of deletion and what the OP's options are. The specific criteria which you are thinking of with respect to deleting a question and it's answers is that there must be <= 1 answer and that answer must A) not have any upvotes (regardless of total score), B) not be accepted, and C) not have received a bounty.

Answer (score 2):

There is overflow. Assuming AL being 8 bits, 128 would become 0. For signed integer there also is signed overflow.

Comment: Learning assembler one instruction and one concept at a time is going to make this a *really* long discussion.  Perhaps you should get a good book or online tutorial.  It will help you ask better questions.